# Issues with symfony2.1 relating to installing DoctrineFixturesBundle via composer

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle

I'm learning symfony by following this tutorial on making a blog: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html

Things have gone swimmingly until I got to the part about installing DoctrineFixturesBundle.  The tutorial is for symf 2.0, and 2.1 installs it differently.  I followed the instructions here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html using composer.

This removed a LOT of vendors, including twig, and now symfony gives me the white screen of death.

Also, my composer.phar file is VERY different, and looks almost corrupted.  Near the top it has this:  __HALT_COMPILER(); ?>^M

The entire file is 35627 lines long, which seems very wrong.

I'm not even sure where to begin looking to fix this.  I'm using version control, so I have an old version of my composer.phar file, do I simply want to get that back and start again?

Here's what my error log spits out:

```
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/srv/http/symblog.dev/app/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/http/symblog.dev/app/autoload.php on line 9
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/http/symblog.dev/web/app.php:0
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. require_once() /srv/http/symblog.dev/web/app.php:6
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. require_once() /srv/http/symblog.dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/srv/http/symblog.dev/app/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/http/symblog.dev/app/autoload.php on line 9
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/http/symblog.dev/web/app.php:0
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. require_once() /srv/http/symblog.dev/web/app.php:6
[Sat Nov 17 16:17:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. require_once() /srv/http/symblog.dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your composer.json file look like? I would redownload composer, check the composer.json file and do a

```
php composer.phar update symfony/symfony
```

Comment: composer.json:
https://gist.github.com/4108040

I ran php composer.phar update symfony/symfony and it says:
    `Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
    Nothing to install or update
    Generating autoload files
    Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call post-update-cmd script
    Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call post-update-cmd script`

Comment: Well, I'd just try to delete the composer.lock file and run

`php composer.phar install`

If that doesn't work, I'd blow out the whole Symfony project directory and start over with a fresh project. :P
Luckily, you're just playing around, anyway.